# Importing global modules concerns

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a performance concern with importing every component and service directly to the `app.module`? If yes, are there any different suggestions?

Comment: This is a very vague question. I don't think this ought to be posted here.

Comment: I want to know if the way I did is correct. What if there are problems with the way I deployed the application. Only that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should only import things you are using elsewhere in the app into app.module as you use them, to register them as imports or providers or what have you, so that your app knows they exist. As your app grows, that list should grow naturally, but it wouldn’t make too much sense to pre-load them all if they’re not even being used.